# Setting date using DialogFragment and Android Annotations

Tags: android, datepicker, android-annotations

I have problem with writing date I selected in DatePicker with Dialog Fragment.
I`m trying to do this using Android Annotations. Problem is, I have to implement behavior for setting this date to TextView on OnDateSet function in DatePickerFragment class.

How can I choose in which TextView, which @Click should write?

Code below:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_main_search)public class SearchActivity extends FragmentActivity{

private int mFYear, mFMonth, mFDay, mTYear, mTMonth, mTDay;

 (R.id.main_search_city)
EditText cityET;

@ViewById(R.id.main_search_price)
EditText priceET;

@ViewById(R.id.main_search_from)
TextView dateFromTV;

@ViewById(R.id.main_search_to)
TextView dateToTV;

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        }
}



@AfterViews
public void setCurrentdateonView(){
     final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     mFYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
     mFMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
     mFDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

     dateFromTV.setText(new StringBuffer().append(mFDay).append("-").append(mFMonth).append("-").append(mFYear).append(""));
     dateToTV.setText(new StringBuffer().append(mFDay).append("-").append(mFMonth).append("-").append(mFYear).append(""));                                 
 }   


@App
HApplication mApp;

@Click(R.id.main_search_from_btn)
public void showFromDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");


}

@Click(R.id.main_search_to_btn)
public void showToDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

@Click(R.id.main_search_btn)
public void openSearch(){
    //SearchActivity_.intent(this).city(cityET.getText().toString()).start();
    ListActivity_.intent(this).city(cityET.getText().toString()).price(priceET.getText().toString()).start();
}}
```

Functions that should realise that date writing are:

@Click(R.id.main_search_from_btn)
    public void showFromDatePickerDialog(View v)

it should write date to dateFromTV

and

@Click(R.id.main_search_to_btn)
    public void showToDatePickerDialog(View v)

it should write date to dateToTV

I SOLVED THE PROBLEM.

What I needed was flags, which were set on each button @Click and then in onDateSet case switch with flag number check. Maybe it will help someone, because it took me whole day to figure it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Click annotation is just for triggering the dialog.
You should implement a callback method through listener interfaces described here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#PassingEvents

EDIT: I implemented a version for myself, here is the code:

MainActivity.java:

```
    package com.example.datepickerexample;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.datepickerexample.DatePickerFragment.DatePickerDialogListener;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        DatePickerDialogListener {
    TextView lbl_from, lbl_to, cpn_from, cpn_to;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        cpn_from = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cpn_from);
        cpn_to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cpn_to);
        lbl_from = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_from);
        lbl_to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_to);
    }

    public void showFromDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("isFromDate", true);
        newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    public void showToDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("isFromDate", false);
        newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDatePicked(DialogFragment dialog, Calendar c,
            boolean isFromDate) {
        String strdate = null;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");

        if (c != null) {
        strdate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
        }
        if (isFromDate) {
            lbl_from.setText(strdate);
        } else {
            lbl_to.setText(strdate);
        }
    }

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cpn_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:text="@string/from_date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/cpn_from"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cpn_from" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_from"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cpn_from"
        android:onClick="showFromDatePickerDialog"
        android:text="@string/pick_from_date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cpn_to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_from"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:text="@string/to_date" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lbl_to"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn_from"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/cpn_to"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cpn_to" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/cpn_to"
        android:onClick="showToDatePickerDialog"
        android:text="@string/pick_to_date" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

DatePickerFragment.java:

```
package com.example.datepickerexample;

import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    public interface DatePickerDialogListener {
        public void onDatePicked(DialogFragment dialog, Calendar c,
                boolean isFromDate);
    }

    // Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
    DatePickerDialogListener mListener;

    boolean isFromDate;

    public static DatePickerFragment newInstance(boolean isFromDate) {
        DatePickerFragment instance = new DatePickerFragment();

        instance = new DatePickerFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putBoolean("isFromDate", isFromDate);
        instance.setArguments(args);
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            isFromDate = getArguments().getBoolean("isFromDate");
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        c.set(year, month, day);
        mListener.onDatePicked(this, c, isFromDate);
    }

    // Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the
    // NoticeDialogListener
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
            // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the
            // host
            mListener = (DatePickerDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well it still looks like solution for sending date to TextViews specified in onDateSet and doesn`t change fact that it can be used only with one date per 2 TextViews at one time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Your interface can have an onToDatePick and an onFromDatePick callback method and you can pass an isFromDate flag to the dialog. Then depending on the flag you call the corresponding method in your dialog.

Comment: I updated my answer. Note the following:
- The Fragment is now a singleton. You can pass arguments to singletons and then pass these arguments as bundled arguments to the onCreate method of the Fragment.
- I have two click listeners here, but you can use one obviously, and decide the arguments depending on the triggering button.
- I ended up using only one method with one flag in the listener.

Comment: I did manage to end this task usign very simple way, with global Integer flag, which was set to 1, when button from clicked and 2, when button to was clicked. Then in onDateSet I wrote case switch, which set date to textView, depending on the flag value.

Also I tried Your code, it works well, thanks for Your attention and time!

Comment: Thank you. Then you should use my code, you will learn (just like I did) that having global flags are not a good habit.